# How did the battleship sink?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman

Near the start of *Wonder Woman (2017)* the Germans, in their pursuit of Steve, stumble across the Amazonian homeland. Outside the magical force-field there is a Battleship that seems to be doing fine. However once the ship breaches the force-field it quickly sinks.

**What happened there? Why did it start sinking?**

Comment: it probably ran into one of the many, many large rocks sticking out of the water.

Comment: @KutuluMike Maybe, but it wasnt really clear in the movie. Would be nice if someone could show what happened

Comment: The 'forcefield' appears to also work as a teleporter (i.e. it is night on the far side of the barrier, and day on the island).  Perhaps bad things happen when a large warship with a deep draft spends a prolonged time straddling the barrier.  Such as rapid water ingress into bisected underwater compartments.  The smaller wooden boats would have a much shallower draft, and thus could be able to safely make the trip across.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Borrowing from my good friend Valorum's [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/161374/21267) on SFF: **it had hit the coral reef.**

---

According to the film's official novelisation, as it passed through the barrier, the battle cruiser hit a hidden reef and was holed below the waterline.

> *Beyond, the enormous ship that had brought the Germans had hit the
> coral reefs. Black, gritty smoke from the sinking battleship swept
> across the reef and over the beach. It smelled like it had come from
> the burning pits of hell.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Wonder Woman: Official Movie Novelisation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1785653784)</sup></sub>

It then sank.

---

The battleship couldn't see that there was an island approaching, as the island was sneakily covered by a sneaky fog.

As such it ventured too close and probably at too high a speed to stop in time. And what happens when a large vessel comes too close to an island?

Comment: If thats the case then they showed that very poorly in the movie